# same object in res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using res.json().

I have an object

`let message =`

```
{
  abc: {
    aplha: 'num'
  }
}
```

Now I am doing `res.json({status: "200", message})`

From this the response I am getting like this:

```
 message: { 
    {
      abc: {
        aplha: 'num'
      }
    }
 }
```

But I want the response like this:

```
      abc: {
        aplha: 'num'
      }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `deconstructing` of objects: `const { abc } = message;` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment